# Resources in VS Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resources, icons, edit

Friend send me a C# project and i have one question becouse he is away from home for a long time.
On files tree are something named "Code.**resources**" and "Resources.**resources**".

#### //**resources** not resx. VS don't now how to open this file.

Build Action is *Embedded Resource*.

### How can i edit this file? In this file are icons? What's that?

Thanks!

PS:
PSS: VS - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012

Comment: Why don't you ask your friend about it?

Comment: "he is away from home for a long time". And i can't contact him. So i asked here